# Oracle SQL to SQLite

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlite

I have following query in  Oracle SQL . How can I convert it to SQLite?

**Oracle Query**

```
SELECT NVL ((SELECT max(quest_no) FROM table1) + 1, '1000000000') quest_no
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: What is your question????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle's `dual` table is typically used for queries that want to compute a single output row without actually accessing a specific table.
SQLite supports standard-conforming SQL here and allows you to omit the FROM clause altogether.

Oracle's `nvl` function allows you to replace NULL values with a string (here it's used to return a default value if there is no maximum, i.e., if `table1` does not contain any `quest_no` values).
In SQLite, you can use the [ifnull](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) or [coalesce](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) functions instead:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT max(quest_no) FROM table1) + 1, 1000000000) quest_no
```

Please note that the subquery with `max` returns a single output row anyway, so it is not necessary to use a subquery:

```
SELECT COALESCE(max(quest_no) + 1, 1000000000) quest_no FROM table1
```

(Oracle supports `COALESCE` too, so this query works in both Oracle and SQLite.)